# Pycharm: Too many values to unpack

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I unpack the values in the `simulate` function?

```
def simulate(to_range=None, iterations=None):
            e = np.finfo(float).eps

            simulated_wk = np.zeros((iterations, self.n_clusters)) + e
            simulated_sk = np.zeros((iterations, self.n_clusters)) + e

            for i in range(iterations):
                self.X = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(300, 2))

                within_cluster_dists = calculate_wk(self.n_clusters, self.df)

                simulated_wk[i] = within_cluster_dists

            wks = np.mean(simulated_wk + e, axis=0)
            sks = np.std(simulated_sk + e, axis=0) * np.sqrt(1 + 1 / 20)

            shifted = np.zeros(to_range)
            shifted[1:] = shift
            shifted[0] = np.nan

            return wks, sks, shifted, simulate()
```

Code that produced an error:

```
wks, sks = simulate(simulations, self.Ks)
```

Error:
Too many values to unpack

Comment: `simulate()` returns 4 values, you are only storing 2.

Comment: the function simulate() is returning 4 values while, you are only storing 2 values as variables. Also, the error has nothing to do with pycharm, so please do not use unnecessary tags..

Comment: Is that the actual code? What's ``self``? How does the recursive ``simulate()`` call even lead to termination, or at least not throw an error from the implied ``range(None)``?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not interested in the orther returned values, you would do

```py
wks, sks, _, _ = simulate(simulations, self.Ks)

# or
wks, sks, *_ = simulate(simulations, self.Ks)
```